# Reading multiple files and operating on stored Arrays

Tags: bash, text-processing, array, for, read

I have 2 text files `"${LinkP}"` and `"${QuestionP}`. I want to read  these files and store each complete line in the respective array,

```
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval "LinkA=($(cat "${LinkP}"))"
IFS=$'\r\n' GLOBIGNORE='*' command eval "QuestionA=($(cat "${QuestionP}"))"
```

Now I want to operate on these using a for loop

```
nLink=${#LinkA[@]} # Size of array
for ((i = 0; i < nLink; i = i + 1)); do
    echo $i
    Question=${QuestionA[i]}
    echo "Question=${QuestionA[i]}"
done
```

But, the `Question` variable doesn't contains full line, it breaks after each space character.

How can I store each question and link (complete line in respective file) in these variable and process them inside for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> store each complete line in the respective array

is easy with a different approach:

```
mapfile LinkA < "$LinkP"
```

See `help mapfile` for more options, such as `-t` to remove a trailing delimiter from each line.